# Submit and Save action in zend form

Tags: forms, zend-framework, button, action, zend-form

I have two submit buttons in my ZEND FORM (zend 1.12) Lets take a scenario:

```
Button Submit-> Action(myproject/submit);

Button Save-> Action(myproject/save);
```

But the buttons are in same Form how can I make the form to post in different pages with respect to the button?

I tried the following and its not working:

```
//store
        $save= new Submit('save');
        $save->setLabel($this->getView()->translate('save'));
        $save->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper',array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div','class'=>'btn-save')),));
        $this->setAction('/myproject/store');
        $this->addElement($save);


//store
        $submit= new Submit('submit');
        $submit->setLabel($this->getView()->translate('submit'));
        $submit->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper',array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div','class'=>'btn-submit')),));
        $submit->setAction('/myproject/submit');
        $this->addElement($submit);
```

If I click any button it post to /myproject/submit' only!!
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `zend_Form` submit elements are differentiated by their *label*, not the name you give the element. Currently your form has 2 submit elements with the same *label* so they will both be represented in the `$_POST` array the same way. Something similar to:

```
array(1) {

    'submit' => 'Store'
}
```

You can give each submit element a unique label and then test for that label to be present in the `$_POST` array.

```
//for example
if($request->isPost()){
    if ($request->getPost('submit') == 'unique Label') {
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

no javascript required...

Comment: I just edited my code, So if the submit is set.. I want to redirect to another page and is save is set I want to redirect to another page? rite? So it means I also want to transfer the post data to the next page. Is there any other way to just make it to post to different page with respect to the action in buttons.

Comment: You can modify the request in the preDispatch action for example like this: $this->getRequest()->setActionName('index');

Comment: you'll probably want to `_forward()` instead of `_redirect()` so you can easily drag the `$_POST` array along. http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.utilmethods

Answer (score 1):

You can't `setAction` on Form Element. Try to use javascript and `onclick /onsubmit` event for both buttons instead.